# Returning a value from entry box to start sense hat timer

Tags: python, tkinter

I am  trying to start a count down timer to display on sense hat when I run the code it doesn't get the value typed into the entry box with no error returned just displays a 0 on the sense hat

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from tkinter import *   

#set up
window = Tk()
window.title('timer')
window.geometry("300x100") #wxh
window.resizable(0,0)


#define and place labels
box1 = Label(window, text="time: ")
box1.grid(row = 1, column = 1,padx = 5, pady = 5)

#define entry box
answerVar = IntVar()
answertext = Entry(window,textvariable=answerVar)
string_answer = answertext.get()
int_answer = int(string_answer)


#display boxes
answertext.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

#define and place buttons
buttonstart = Button( window,text ='start:', command=lambda:int_answer)

sense = SenseHat()

G = [128,0,128]  #led color    
for i in range(int_answer,-1,-1): #create range start from input, stop at 
                                  #0 is -1
#decrease in steps is -1  Range is only a number

    sense.show_letter(str(i),G) 

exitbtn = Button( window,text ='Exit', command=exit)

#place buttons
buttonstart.grid(row = 4, column = 1,padx = 1, pady = 1)
exitbtn.grid(row = 4, column = 2,padx = 1, pady = 1)


#display window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why use `IntVar` if still going to use `answertext.get` instead of `answerVar.get`?

Comment: That `for` loop seem to run before user has a chance to type in anything.

Comment: `mainloop` creates window and starts all work. Everything before `mainloop` is executed before window is shown on screen. You can use `after()` to run function periodicaly - example [timer-using-after](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after) And use `command=` to start function which get data from Entry and use to display timer.

Comment: You are correct it was redundant.

Comment: I added a function to be called by the buttondef timer():
    for i in range(answerVar.get(),-1,-1): #create range start from input, stop at 0 is -1
    #decrease in steps is -1  Range is only a number
        sense.show_letter(str(i),G) # use sense API to show letter convert range to
    #string show letter on sense hat using color defined must be a string
        sleep(1)buttonstart = Button( window,text ='start:', command=lambda:timer)